# How does setKeepAlive in node.js work and how to implement it?

Tags: sockets, node.js, tcp

Cannot understand the philosophy of setKeepAlive method in Node.js' net sockets. What happens after initialDelay finishes?

Answer (score 9):

This method controls TCP keep-alive functionality on the underlying TCP socket. Check out [this article](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/) for information on TCP Keepalive. Here's a snippet that explains what `initialDelay` (the "keepalive timer") does:

> ## 2.1. What is TCP keepalive?
>
> The keepalive concept is very simple: when you set up a TCP connection, you associate a set of timers. Some of these timers deal with the keepalive procedure. When the keepalive timer reaches zero, you send your peer a keepalive probe packet with no data in it and the ACK flag turned on. You can do this because of the TCP/IP specifications, as a sort of duplicate ACK, and the remote endpoint will have no arguments, as TCP is a stream-oriented protocol. On the other hand, you will receive a reply from the remote host (which doesn't need to support keepalive at all, just TCP/IP), with no data and the ACK set.
>
> If you receive a reply to your keepalive probe, you can assert that the connection is still up and running without worrying about the user-level implementation. In fact, TCP permits you to handle a stream, not packets, and so a zero-length data packet is not dangerous for the user program.
>
> This procedure is useful because if the other peers lose their connection (for example by rebooting) you will notice that the connection is broken, even if you don't have traffic on it. If the keepalive probes are not replied to by your peer, you can assert that the connection cannot be considered valid and then take the correct action.